# Can a build task call other tasks in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

I'm new to TFS and I was wondering if I can create many build tasks and then have another build task to automatically call them all.

So, I'd have taskA, taskB, taskC, which I can call individually, to deploy modules A, B and C, but I'd also have another task taskAll which I'd call and that one would be in charge of calling the other 3.

Is this possible? It seems very standard to be able to do something like that, but I couldn't find any task when adding a build step that seems to do that.

Comment: The build tasks in VSTS are sequential, so a TaskAll doesn't make much sense, unless you're trying soemthing that's not really how the build tasks are intended to use. It may be that you're looking for Task Groups, which would allow you to re-use task definitions and which can be nested... https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/task-groups

Comment: PS: the TFS version makes a big difference.

Comment: Jesse is right. With the release of Task Conditions https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/conditions you can have a flag dinamically control the execution of task, and you can use a Task Group to reuse your logic

Comment: that seems what I'm looking for, I'll have a look at it, thanks

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: It's on hold at the moment, but I'll get back once I have some time and will share the answer.